# My kirby website wasn't hosted(I'm totally new to this)

Tags: content-management-system, kirby

I watched a tutorial about hosting a website using Kirby
and read the documentation on Kirby official website.

As far as I followed,
What I had to do is downloading starter-kit and go to domain and register that.

(I have my license key- Kirby 3 License and the licenses page shows my domain)

After I registered my license in my panel from my kirby template.(now the register button is gone).

When I visit my website url shown on my license page "soonkpaik.com".
It wasn't published on the web yet.

What am I missing now?
Really Can't find any documentation nor tutorial about it.
I assume there is an extreme basic thing for publishing my page on the web that Kirby and youtubers assume that I already know.

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps linking to the tutorial you followed would help others give better answers? Just a thought in case you still don't have your answers… Hopefully you found a way around this since last March :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kirby doesn't help at all with deployment or publishing as far as I know. That's considered a separate concern. You'll have to find a PHP-enabled host on which you can manually launch a Kirby instance, similarly to how you launched it on your local machine.

Some (rare) web hosts offer some helpers to get started with Kirby. The only one I've found is A2hosting (which I don't recommend), which provides you with a relatively standard (and horribly broken) cPanel environment along with the Softaculous software installer. Once in Softwaculous, you can find the Kirby installer by clicking on the Wordpress installer (ironically enough) and searching for Kirby.